# Solving for $A$ in the equation $AP=PD$, and finding $A^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrices $$\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} -4 & -15 \\ 2 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{D} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
(a) Find a formula for $\mathbf{D}^n$ for positive integer $n$.

(b) There exists a matrix
$$\mathbf{P } = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & a \\ b & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ such that $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{P} = \mathbf{P} \mathbf{D}$.
Solve for $\mathbf{P}$.

(c) Find an expression for $\mathbf{A}$ in terms of $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ using matrix operations.

(d) Use part (c) to find a formula for $\mathbf{A}^n$ for positive integer $n$ with an explicit expression for each of its entries. Prove that your formula is correct.

I've solved part A and B. For part C, I was thinking to isolate A by dividing PD by P, but I'm confused on the properties of matrices part, and how to simplify that.

I have no idea how to do D, but the problem says to use part C, so I need to solve that first.

Comment: For (c), right multiply both sides by $\mathbf P^{-1}$. For (d), see what $\mathbf A^n$ looks like when you write it out using your expression from (c).

Comment: Please improve your title.  "need help on part C and D" tells the reader (and the search algorithm) nothing about the problem at hand.  Start with something closer to:  "solving for a matrix in an equation..." and then refine it.

Comment: kipf, in part (c), we multiply both sides by P^-1 and get A=PDP^-1. How do I simplify this?

Comment: @TristanLi That's the answer - you can't simplify any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (c), right-multiplying both sides of $\mathbf{AP} = \mathbf{PD}$ by $\mathbf P^{-1}$ gives $$\mathbf A = \mathbf P \mathbf D \mathbf P^{-1}.$$

For (d), observe that \begin{align*}
\mathbf A^n &= \left(\mathbf{PDP}^{-1}\right)^n \\
& = \underbrace{\left(\mathbf{PDP}^{-1}\right)\left(\mathbf{PDP}^{-1}\right)\cdots \left(\mathbf{PDP}^{-1}\right)}_{n \text{ times}} \\
&= \mathbf P \mathbf D \left(\mathbf P^{-1} \mathbf P\right) \mathbf D \left(\mathbf P^{-1} \mathbf P\right) \mathbf D \left(\mathbf P^{-1} \mathbf P\right) \cdots \mathbf{PDP}^{-1} \\
&= \mathbf P \underbrace{\mathbf {DD} \cdots \mathbf D}_{n \text{ times}} \mathbf P^{-1} \\
&= \mathbf P \mathbf D^n \mathbf P^{-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't understand how you go from the 2nd step to the third, can you help?

Comment: @TristanLi I've just regrouped terms a little. The idea is that $\mathbf P^{-1} \mathbf P = \mathbf I$, the identity, so all the middle $\left(\mathbf P^{-1} \mathbf P \right)$ terms cancel to just leave $\mathbf D^n$.

Comment: I thought matrices don't commute? How can these terms be rearranged?

Comment: I've not swapped the order of any matrices.

Comment: @TristanLi associative law is applied.

Comment: oh, now i see, thank you @kipf and @user376343!